# Ocaml - how do I explicitly declare the list mutable type

Tags: ocaml, declaration, explicit

I tried something like:

```
let lchars : char ref list = ref [];;
```

but don't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameterized OCaml types are specified in postfix order, so the type `char ref list` is first and foremost a list. In other words, it's a list of references to char:

```
let (x: char ref list) = [ ref 'a'; ref 'b']
```

Similarly, the type `char list ref` is first and foremost a reference. It's a reference to a list of chars:

```
let (y: char list ref) = ref ['a'; 'b']
```

You wanted the second of these types but your code specifies the first type.

Answer (score 0):

```
let lchars : char list ref = ref[];;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about this solution? I would liek to understand why.